# How to check a zpicode in checkout cart summary block in magento 2

Tags: magento2, zipcode, checkout-summary

How to check a zpicode in checkout cart  summary block in magento 2 like below image

[image]

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: no i didn`t try anything